# Solr Warming Up Doubts

Tags: solr, solr6

Whenever i am running the full-import, my response time for some request increases from 80ms to 3000ms.

This must be indicating my poor choice of warming up.

**1. newSearcher**
I have added some 2 frequent used query but all my autowarmCount are set to 0. I have also added facet for warming.
So if my autowarmCount=0, does this mean by queries are not getting cached.

**2. useColdSearcher = false**
Despite reading many document, i am not able to understand how it works after full import (assuming this is not my first full-import)

**3. not defined maxWarmingSearchers in solrconfig.**

Am i doing anything wrong as why my autowarm is not working proprtly?

Note: I am using solr6.6.0

Comment: Why must it indicate a poor choice of cache warming? Maybe the server is just overloaded when it doesn't have any caches, or maybe it's spending too much time warming - look at the logs and try to understand what's happening - are there any particular queries that spend more time than others? How often are those queries run? If you have autowarmCount set to 0 - why? Don't you want the cache to be warmed with existing queries?

Comment: I guess i should increase autowarmCount count. whats should be the ideal no. Also is there any way by which i can know that autowarm is completed?

Comment: You can see how long the warmup took for [each cache endpoint](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/performance-statistics-reference.html). I'm guessing the solr log will show the warmup queries as well.